# Прокрутка td с вложенным pre

Tags: css

Вот есть [страница](http://jsfiddle.net/B7PZ9/).
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при слишком больном количестве текста в правом td появлялась полоса прокрутки (именно в нем, чтобы левый td не прокручивался) или переносился текст на новую строку?

Comment: Можно зафигачить div как враппер и ему поставить overflow: auto

Comment: Так я так делал. Надо, чтобы прокручивался именно правый td, а левый оставался при прокрутке правого на месте.

Comment: Проблема решена с помощью 

    white-space: pre-wrap;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/B7PZ9/19/

Comment: опоздал малек :). Не получилось правда полосу прокрутки опустить вниз ячейки, как не пробовал